# How to round off the memory value in percentage for the below code?

Tags: shell-script

do
        hostname=$(ssh ${i} hostname -s)

```
    memory=$(ssh ${i} free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf(" %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}')
    mem_health=$(ssh ${i} free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf(" %.2f%"), $3/$2*100}')
    if [ ${mem_health} -ge 80 ];
    then
            mem_health="CRITICAL"
    else
            mem_health="NORMAL"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
mem_health=$(ssh ${i} free -t | awk 'FNR == 2 {printf(" %d"), $3/$2*100}')
```

i.e. use `%d` rather than `%.2f%` as you want an integer and don't want a percentage sign in the mem_health variable.